# I can boot from USB a installation of Windows 7, but I can't do this with Ubuntu or XBMC live

Tags: boot, windows, usb, cd

I'm using a old pc with Intel Pentium 4, 1gb ram, 200gb HD
All this night I tried to boot Ubuntu from USB...
I can do this with Windows 7 normally

I tried first using Startup Disk Creator, but freezes.
I tried using UNetbootin, freezes too, choosing any option
I tried CD, but continues the boot of windows the a I have installed
So, I tried booting a Easeus Partition from boot, and work, and I format my disks normally
But anyway, when I boot Ubuntu, don't work...

I don't know what I do to install Ubuntu in my PC, I need help...

Thanks

P.S.: Sorry my english, I'm from Brazil

---

I'll explain using my language and translated in Google Translate
Then again explaining ...
I am able to boot the Windows installation via USB, works perfectly, but when I do this using the Ubuntu image, it simply does not start.

I followed all the steps from the Ubuntu site itself to make a bootable usb using the Startup Disk Creator program, I create perfectly and when I boot, just hangs/freezes on a purple screen.
So I tried using UNetbootin, I create perfectly on usb but when I boot hangs/freezes on the choice of options.
So I finally put the image on a CD of Ubuntu, and also does not work ...

I'm not having trouble creating a bootable USB, but the problem is own boot screen.
I chose the option to boot from USB, it recognizes and simply does not work.

I was able to install Ubuntu on my Sony Vaio notebook, but this PC I can not in any way.

I can install windows via usb as many times as I want, but Ubuntu is not working.

P.S.: The same thing happens with the XBMC live

Comment: Does this computer have a 32bit CPU or a 64bit CPU? And are you using 32bit Ubuntu for a 32bit CPU and not 64bit Ubuntu? Ubuntu 32bit will work on both 32bit CPU and 64bit CPU but Ubuntu 64bit will not run on 32bit CPU. Please confirm that you are not making this error. Pentium 4 are old machines. Does it have a 32bit CPU?

Answer (score 1):

If you write a bootable ISO of Ubuntu to your USB stick, and your PC can boot from USB then it will work. I am a little puzzled when you say you can install Windows from a USB stick though. Really?

The links below do give some caveats, some hardware just will not work, but basically, the idea is to run the installer (like Windows, the Ubuntu installer will let you wipe and create partitions for your install. I can't understand what you mean by running startup disk creator - are you saying you have an install image or you are failing to create one?)

[This link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Creating_a_bootable_Ubuntu_USB_flash_drive) will talk you through how to create a bootable USB Ubuntu stick from Windows or Mac, then the [full article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) shows how to run a full installation from that USB stick.

Comment: You can do USB installs of Windows, yes.

Comment: I'm Lúcio, and I edit the post, explaining again...

Comment: @Oli - no, I meant the process of making a bootable USB installer should be the same no matter which OS, pretty much. I'm thinking the Ubuntu ISO image may be faulty

Comment: May be Lucio is creating the Ubuntu live USB from the Ubuntu that he says is installed on a Sony Vaio notebook. Have you though of that? The issue here is not the creation of the install disk but, what is the answer to a live CD/USB loading as far as the purple screen and no further?

Comment: @grahammechanical I created the ubuntu usb by the Windows using UNetbooin and by the Ubuntu using the Startup Disk Creator and UNetbootin... And happens the same thing. When I created from Startup Disk Creator, the boot freezes on purple screen with two symbol in bottom...

Answer (score 0):

Things you need : 1GB or higher USB stick / Ubuntu ISO / windows PC
Step 1: Boot from windows and go to http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/#button
OR simply click [here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/Universal-USB-Installer/Universal-USB-Installer-1.8.8.3.exe) to download the software.
Step 2: Open the downloaded software.
Step 3: Follow the instructions and create the bootable USB stick
Step 4: Reboot the PC with USB.
Step 5: Install Ubuntu as usuall!!!!

Think this will helpful.